# How can I import all variable files from a directory which is external to the role? include_vars or vars_files?

Tags: ansible

How can I import all variable files from a directory which is external to the role?

I have a directory structure similar to this:

```
├── playbooks
│   ├── roles
│   │   └── some_role
│   │       ├── tasks
│   │       │   └── main.yml
│   │       └── vars
│   │           └── local_vars
│   │               ├── var_fileA
│   │               ├── var_fileB
│   │               └── var_fileC
│   └── some_play.yml
└── vars
    └── external_vars
        ├── var_file1
        ├── var_file2
        └── var_file3
```

I am trying to import all files from within the *ansible/vars/external_vars* directory but I cannot seem to achieve this with `include_vars` or `vars_files`.

I can use `vars_files` but I have to add each file as I cannot use a directory path (that I know of...):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
     - role: roles/users
  vars_files:
     - "../vars/external_vars/var_file1"
     - "../vars/external_vars/var_file2"
     - "../vars/external_vars/var_file3"
```

This is not useable as the number of variable files changes regularly. So, having to change this constantly isn't viable.

My other option was using `include_vars` from within the role, however, I cannot seem to use a path to a directory external to the role. For example, the following does not work:

```yaml
- name: Include all vars files.
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    dir: ../../vars/external_vars/
```

Including the entire directory does work if I had the vars within the role like below, but this isn't viable as the vars I need are external to the role:

```yaml
- name: Include all vars files.
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    dir: vars/local_vars
```

Is there something I'm missing to be able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`playbook_dir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-playbook_dir) special variable:

```yaml
- name: Include all vars files.
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    dir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../vars/external_vars/"
```

Note that the variables loaded with `vars_files` have lower precedence than `include_vars`, and the role variables have [higher precedence than both](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

Answer (score 1):

Since your first trial indicates that you are fine with having the variables files included at the play level, you could use an `include_vars` task in a `pre_tasks`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Include all vars files.
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        dir: vars/external_vars
  roles:
     - role: roles/users
```

Comment: Yes, i would be happy to do this in the playbook level.  pre_tasks are definitely useful for this, and would work.  However, I have chosen to use the {{ playbook_dir }} variable at the role level instead.  Thanks anyway.